# PartCover producing empty xml when upgrading applications to .Net 4.0

Tags: nunit, code-coverage, partcover

We have been running PartCover on applications, and they were producing xml reports just fine. However, we upgraded all our applications from .Net 3.5 to .Net 4.0, and now, PartCover just produces an empty XML file. I tried upgrading to latest NUnit and latest PartCover, but that did not help. Is there anything else I can do to try to resolve this issue? We've been using code coverage frequently as part of our process, and need to resolve.

This is the command:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\PartCover\PartCover .NET 4.0\PartCover.exe" --target "C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.5.10\bin\net-2.0\nunit-console-x86.exe"  --target-args "{dll of app to coverr} /xml=results1.xml /noshadow" --settings {xml file for settings} --output CoverageReport.xml

Comment: From the information you have given everything looks right. Is the profiler registered? You can see entries in the Application Eventlogs when a process loads a profiler.

Comment: How do I register the profiler? I don't see anything in the EventLogs. In the output, I do get a message "CorProfiler is turned off".

Comment: The profiler normally registers itself when you install, however under an administrative console use regsvr2 Partcover.dll, there is a utility called Partcover.registration.exe which will do per user registration.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working. I uninstalled and reinstalled PartCover and that did the trick. Thanks for the help.