# PartCover generates empty output xml file

Tags: nunit, code-coverage, partcover

I am using PartCover to produce code coverage report. I have used below command line,

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PartCover\PartCover .NET 4.0\PartCover.exe" 
--target-work-dir Debug 
--target "C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.2\bin\nunit-console-x86.exe"  
--target-args "Test.dll /noshadow /xml=Reports\NUnitResults.xml"
--include [*Test*]* 
--output Reports\Report.xml
```

Output xml file contains below lines only,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PartCoverReport date="2015-04-23T16:18:14.5723939-05:00" version="4.0"/>
```

I tried to uninstall PartCover and reinstall but did not work. (as pe [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944633/partcover-producing-empty-xml-when-upgrading-applications-to-net-4-0?rq=1))

Any idea what the issue is ? Please show me right direction.

Here is console output,

[image]

Comment: PartCover has since been superseeded by [OpenCover](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover)

Comment: Yeah that's right. I saw few posts regarding this. But our application is not allowing currently to make use of OpenCover. Could you please guide me to resolve the issue in PartCover?

Comment: without your code it is very hard to determine what the issue is - why not try a filter like `[*]*` - it'll be slow but you can then start to reduce the filtering to target your application code - which I assume is not in your 'Test' assembly

Comment: After using [*] xml file is generated but it is does not contain expected application code. We have same code on two servers. On both servers .net 4.5 is installed. On first server xml is generated fine. I compared console output of both servers and found that CLR version used by partcover is different in both. On first server CLR version used by partcover is "CLR Version: 4.0.30319.18408 ( Net 4.5 )". But on second server CLR version used by partcover is "2.0.50727.5448 ( Net 3.5 )" as you can see output in original post. I would like to know, why second server is using NET 3.5 and not 4.5?

Comment: Probably something to with a difference in your server environments

Comment: Server-1 (64-bit) : Sample test dll generates xml  

Server-2 (64-bit) : Sample test dll generates xml  

Server-1 (64-bit) : My application dll generates xml  

Server-2 (64-bit) : My application dll does not generate xml  

I am not sure if it is enviroment difference because for test dll, xml report generated properly.
Is there anything that I need to take care of in order to generate proper xml.

Comment: I couldn't tell you, as I said its environmental (and so without access to your servers I'd just be guessing and probably wrongly and wasting your time) - I haven't used PartCover myself for years as it was so problematical